# How to find 10 items that sold the most in the last year?

Tags: sql, sapb1

I need a list of the top 10 best selling items in the last year.
I am required to use `dateadd`.

In my opinion, `fromdate` and `dateto` should also be used, but I didn't succeed.

I would appreciate your help

```
SELECT
    RDR1.ItemCode [Itemcode],
    RDR1.Quantity [Quantity],
    YEAR(RDR1.DocDate) [DocDate]
FROM 
    ORDR
INNER JOIN 
    RDR1 ON ORDR.DocEntry = RDR1.DocEntry
WHERE 
    RDR1.DocDate BETWEEN (@date) AND (YEAR(GETDATE())- 1)
    -- RDR1.DocDate BETWEEN  (@DateTo) AND (@date)
GROUP BY 
    (RDR1.ItemCode)
ORDER BY 
    SUM(RDR1.Quantity) DESC
```

Comment: Hi - for a start, you have a GROUP BY clause but no aggregate functions in your SELECT clause. Also, you are comparing DocDate (which is presumably a date?) to a year - which is not going to work; you need to compare it to a date which is one year less than your date parameter, hence the need to use DATEADD with a negative value in one of its parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 20 T1.ItemCode, T2.ItemName, cast(sum(T1.Quantity) as numeric) as 'Quantity Sold', sum(T1.LineTotal - T1.VatSum) as 'Total Net Value', sum(T1.LineTotal) as 'Total Gross Value', T1.Currency

FROM dbo.INV1 T1 inner join OINV T3 on T1.docentry = t3.docentry
LEFT OUTER JOIN OITM T2 on T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode INNER JOIN OCRD T4 ON T2.CardCode = T4.CardCode INNER JOIN OCRG T5 ON T4.GroupCode = T5.GroupCode

WHERE T1.ItemCode is not null and (t3.docdate between [%0] and [%1]) and t3.series = 229 and T5.GroupName = '[%2]'

GROUP BY T1.ItemCode, T2.ItemName, T1.Currency

order by sum(T1.Quantity) desc
```

Hope this helps :)